# Метод prisma.create создает пустой объект

Tags: javascript, postgresql, backend, prisma

Пишу backend простенького  приложеняе для тренировок. В проекте использую postgresql и prisma orm. на определенном этапе столкнулась с проблемой: при создании упражнения в insomnia возвращается пустой объект. Использую метод create в prisma:

```
export const createExercise = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
const { name, times, iconPath } = req.body;
const exercise = prisma.exercise.create({
  data: {
    name,
    times,
    iconPath,
  },
});
res.json(exercise);
});
```

Вот модель упражнения в схеме prisma

```
model Exercise {
id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
createdAt DateTime  @default(now()) @map("created_at")
updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
iconPath  String    @map("icon_path")
name      String    @unique
times     Int
workouts  Workout[]
}
```

При использовании console.log(exercise) вывод следующий

```
{
then: [Function: then],
catch: [Function: catch],
finally: [Function: finally],
requestTransaction: [Function: requestTransaction],
[Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)]: 'PrismaPromise'
}
```

Вывод в insomnia
[image: Вывод в insomnia]

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите в чем дело и как это исправить? Я пробовала использовать метод createMany - результат тот же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пропустили **await**. Должно быть

```js
const exercise = await prisma.exercise.create({
```

Поэтому в `exercise` у вас находится не ожидаемый объект, а промис. В ответе приходит пустой объект - результат конвертации промиса в JSON

Comment: точно, я забыла про него) спасибо)